# I need some help getting parameters to go through with my AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm making a call with ajax to my db to get some data. And I try to limit it to a specific Id. And I got the backend working. it works when I visit the specific localhost url or when I call it from Postman. I then get the expected value. However when I try to make a call from my client with AJAX I just don't get anything at all. I got into a thing where sometimes it would work and sometimes it didn't.

```
const GetUserById = (id) => {
    let url = "/Users/1";
    $.get(url, (gotUser) => {
        alert(gotUser.id);
    })
}
```

I have this method that I just hardcoded to go to /Users/1 for testing purposes. And when I call this in postman or go to localhost:8080/Users/1 I get the thing I expect. However here It just doesn't go anywhere at all.

```
app.get("/Users/:id", (request, response) => {
    let sqlCode = "select Id, Username, [Password], Credits from Users Where Id = " + request.params.id;

    sql.query(connString, sqlCode, (error, result) => {

        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            response.json(result);
        }
    });
});
```

The server side if that's interesting.

EDIT: added a try catch like this. it doesn't even get to the catch. It get's to the line that's $.get(url, (gotUser) => { then it goes to the end of the function and doesn't get anything.

```
 try {
        $.get(url, (gotUser) => {
            alert(gotUser.id);
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Comment: How is `GetUserById` called? Add an error handler to the Ajax call.

Comment: What happens when you debug?  Are there any errors on the browser console?  In the debugging tools, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Have you confirmed that this function is being called at all?

Comment: added an edit now @epascarello and David, I get no console errors or anything. And the weirdest part is that i get the data I'm expecting everywhere else except from this call. 

David the function is called in another function.

Comment: That is not how you would get an error....

`$.get(...).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.error(textStatus, errorThrown); });`

Comment: I asked this once and I will ask this again, how is `GetUserById` called?

Answer (score 1):

A typical issue with processing ajax requests are CORS. In your case a quick fix to that would be to specify at the response headers to allow the origins, like that:

```
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

In a more general way you might need to specify it in application level, or use any package to deal with that(cors).
EDIT ---

```
app.get("/Users/:id", (request, response) => {
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    let sqlCode = "select Id, Username, [Password], Credits from Users Where Id = " + request.params.id;

    sql.query(connString, sqlCode, (error, result) => {

        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            response.json(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. This is done server side?

Comment: Yes, just edited the answer to fit your code. If it works do not forget to mark it as the accepted answer and upvote so others find it easier and we do not get repeated questions.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a cors issue try something along these lines

```
var cors = require('cors');
    
app.get("/Users/:id",cors(), (request, response) => {
            let sqlCode = "select Id, Username, [Password], Credits from Users Where Id = " + request.params.id;
        
sql.query(connString, sqlCode, (error, result) => {
        
     if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                else {
                    response.json(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).